# methods aren't getting called after adding class as observer for notifications

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I have a class called CoreSpotlight(NSObject class), in this class I have methods that need to respond to notifications. I'm trying to create an instance of this class in the app delegate and I called the method to add the instance itself as observer.

```
func addCoreSpotLightAsObserverForItemInstallerNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "addNewInstalledItemToSpotlightIndex:", name: "ItemInstallerItemInstalledNotification", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "removeUninstalledItemFromSpotlightIndex:", name: "ItemInstallerItemUninstalledNotification", object: nil)
    NSLog("Corespotlight added as observer///////////////////////////////////////////")
}
```

This is how I'm calling the method in the app delegate in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
let coreSpotlightInstanceClass = CoreSpotlight()
    coreSpotlightInstanceClass.addCoreSpotLightAsObserverForItemInstallerNotifications()
```

For some reason the methods aren't responding to the notifications. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your instance of `CoreSpotlight` as a local variable inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, so as soon as this function exits the object will be released.

You should create an instance property to store the reference;

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    let spotlightHandler = CoreSpotlight()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.spotlightHandler.addCoreSpotLightAsObserverForItemInstallerNotifications()
        return true
    }
```

Although your code would be cleaner if you just invoked `addCoreSpotLightAsObserverForItemInstallerNotifications` (I have to say this is a pretty terrible function name too) in the CoreSpotlight `init` function.  Then you wouldn't need to do anything other than instantiate an instance of that class in  retained variable.

Comment: lol yeah I need to work on the names. what do yo mean "Although your code would be cleaner if you just invoked addCoreSpotLightAsObserverForItemInstallerNotifications"

Comment: If you put the contents of `addCoreSpotLightAsObserverForItemInstallerNotifications` into the `init()` method for `CoreSpotlight` then the observer would be registered in the line `let spotlightHandler = CoreSpotlight()` and you wouldn't need any code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: In my case I created an object in local method, So the observer class dealloc during notification fire from another class. You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67328439/nsnotificationcenter-addobserver-not-working-in-release-mode-but-works-in-debug