# NSnotificationcenter addobserver not working in Release Mode, but works in Debug mode

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

I found an issue, I have a project which has both Swift and objective - C files. I have added NSnotificationcenter addobserver, which works fine in debug mode, but when I generate IPA (release mode) then it does not work. I have added observer in `Objective-C` class and posting it from Swift class.

> **Swift Class: On a button click**

```
@IBAction func btnBackTapped(_ sender: Any) {
let testManager = TestManager.init(window: appdel?.window, andApplicationViewController: splitViewController!)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue:"test"), object: nil)}
```

**> Objectice - Class:**

```
-(id)initWithWindow:(UIWindow *)w andApplicationViewController:(UIViewController *)avc {
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(testMethod:) name:@"test" object:nil];
    
}
return self;
```

}

```
   -(void)testMethod:(NSNotification *)notification {
      NSLog(@"testMethod called ");
   }
```

**Notes:** I have noticed one more thing once I work with Xcode 11 version then it works in both cases. (Release and debug mode works fine). The issue only I faced in Xcode 12 versions, debug mode only. I found the issue and fixed now working fine even in debug mode.
**Issue:** I have created an object of class TestManager in the local method. So class destroys at the time notification fire. That's why the other class notification method does not call.
**Fixes:** I have created the object of class TestManager as Global instead of local method. And now working fine.

I have posted this question for two reasons: **First one:** if someone facing the same issue then can try, as I searched a couple of hours then I was not able to find the issue, because as this issue was only in debug mode, So I was not aware of how to run release mode in Xcode and set breakpoint. I found a way by which you can run from Xcode in release mode as well, no need to create IPA and install it every time. Go to edit scheme > Select run and info tab > Build confirmation > change it debug mode.

**Second:** May please someone tell me why it works in debug mode and why does not work in release mode when I created another class object in the local method instead of global. Any suggestion will be great, Thanks in advance. Happy coding.

Comment: hope you did not place a syntax sugar #define to rule out NSLog from printing in release mode. Because if so, it would work but you wouldn't get a log to see it. You could use `fprintf(stderr,@"success")` instead just to make sure you really print to logs.

Comment: @OlSen I did not modify NSLog. In this posed question, my query is why the same code works in debug mode and why does not work in release mode when I create another class object in the local method instead of global. When I create a global object then it works in both cases (Debug and Release Mode). But why ??

Comment: I think it may be related to the App Performance. For example, Apple takes care (memory management, object allocation/deallocation) more deeply in the case of Release mode, That's why in my case in debug model object doesn't deallocate in debug mode but deallocate in release mode. Have someone can advise on this, please?? Am I on right track OR something else here??

Comment: As you work with ObjC and Swift in combination, Xcode 12 (Xcode11.3...) introduced a new log mechanism with `os_log` you should be aware of. The use of `fprintf(stderr,@"success")` from inside ObjC makes sure it is not an NSLog issue, as this is basically the underlaying mechanism that is called to log anyway. 
In your code `let testManager` is a local scoped variable that may be invalid before the notification can even be observed. Yes Debug modes slow the app processes down by applying more work to trace whats going on in memory (depending on your scheme settings).

Comment: if your `testManager` is truly a global then you don't need the `let` declaring it a local one.